How could Big bang happen everywhere if space is expanding
Reading different articles and watching science videos I realise that Big Bang happened everywhere. However, this 'everywhere' was a very small volume of space and that due to expansion has grown into current size. Also, the expansion happens because every point in space is expanding.
This brings me to my question that can we really say at this moment of time that Big Bang happened everywhere?
Even if we ignore what is happening at the Planck scale due to this intrinsic expansion, atleast we can say that more volume is being added with every moment of time. So how can we say that this newly added volume have a history that stretches back to the Big Bang? Because if the newly added volume's causal history can be traced back to Big Bang then it would imply that somehow at a given moment a definite volume of space somehow divides to create more volume. I say this because I don't see any other way to preserve a causal chain for the newly added volume.

Space as we know it is a product of the big bang (as we understand it). Accordingly, all existing space was part of the bang.

This question is similar to: Does space expand?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32243/what-does-it-mean-for-space-to-expand

@Mithoron Are you saying that at the Planck scale more "space" gets added? Or it is some sort of mathematical metric that measures distance between two points starts to give increasing value with time?

Metric gives increasing value. I don't think we really know what it means for the space on fundamental level.

Yes, we can. All space was a part of the big bang. The fact that that space later expanded doesn't mean it wasn't previously part of it.
Imagine you have a non-blown up balloon. You then blow it up, and it vastly increases in size. All parts of the blown up balloon were in it before it you blew it up, just closer together. Isn't this "a definite volume of space [that] somehow divides to create more volume"?

The Big Bang isn't at the center of 3D space. Space has no center. Ants on an expanding balloon can't find the center of their balloon, either.
We're on the surface of an expanding balloon too, only the surface is 3-dimensional.
The Big Bang is in the center of the universe, but only when you see things as they really are, in 4 dimensions.

